# php contact form is not working, error message & bouncing back

Tags: php, web, contacts

So im really bad when it comes to php forms, im getting the message "Sorry,
Your message can't be send...check if your email is correct otherwise a field is missing..."

other people are using the site saying it is bouncing back also.

[HOW IT LOOKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KhDV.png)

[PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUgp5.png)

The folder isnt in a php foler it is out with the html pages.

```
<?php
//set your email here:
$yourEmail = 'emma@peacehavengc.com';
/*
 * CONTACT FORM
 */
//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) { 
    //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
    if($_POST['contact_name'] === '') { 
            $hasError = true;
    } else {
            $name = $_POST['contact_name'];
    }

    //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
    if($_POST['emma@peacehavengc.com'] === '')  { 
            $hasError = true;
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}$/i", $_POST['emma@peacehavengc.com'])) {
            $hasError = true;
    } else {
            $email = $_POST['emma@peacehavengc.com'];
    }

    //Check to make sure comments were entered  
    if($_POST['contact_textarea'] === '') {
            $hasError = true;
    } else {
            if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
                    $comments = stripslashes($_POST['contact_textarea']);
            } else {
                    $comments = $_POST['contact_textarea'];
            }
    }

    //If there is no error, send the email
    if(!isset($hasError)) {

            $emailTo = $yourEmail;
            $subject = "Message From Your Website";
            $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments";
            $headers = 'From : my site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'answer to : ' . $email;

            mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

            $emailSent = true; 
    }

}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
    <h3>Get in touch Now</h3>
</div>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="contact.php" id="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contact_name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_name" name="contact_name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contact_email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact_email" name="contact_email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contact_textarea" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="contact_textarea" name="contact_textarea"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submitted"><i class="icon-paperplane"></i>Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you add your code to the question, please?

Comment: what is this $_POST['emma@peacehavengc.com']; ? do you have any input name like this ??

Comment: paste code of HTML contact form too

Comment: i dont i think i did that bit wrong, i only need to put the email of the person it needs to reach at the top right?

Comment: show your contact form.

Comment: " i dont i think i did that bit wrong," ..  you understood.. see your contact form

Comment: I have changed all the emails i put in back to "contact_email" apart from the very top one, still not working :/

Comment: http://www.peacehavengc.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This.

```
<?php
    $yourEmail = 'emma@peacehavengc.com';
    if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) 
    { 
        if($_POST['contact_name'] == '') 
        { 
                $hasError = true;
            } 
        else 
        {
                $name = $_POST['contact_name'];
            }

            //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
            if($_POST['contact_email'] == '')  
        { 
                $hasError = true;
            } 
        else if (!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}$/i", $_POST['contact_email'])) 
        {
                $hasError = true;
            } 
        else 
        {
                $email = $_POST['contact_email'];
            }

            //Check to make sure comments were entered  
            if($_POST['contact_textarea'] == '') 
        {
                $hasError = true;
            } 
        else 
        {
                if(function_exists('stripslashes')) 
            {
                        $comments = stripslashes($_POST['contact_textarea']);
                    } 
            else 
            {
                        $comments = $_POST['contact_textarea'];
                    }
            }

            //If there is no error, send the email
            if(!isset($hasError)) 
        {

                $emailTo = $yourEmail;
                $subject = "Message From Your Website";
                $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments";            
        $headers  = "From: my site <$emailTo>" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;\n\tcharset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";

                mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

                $emailSent = true; 
            }
    header("location:contact.html");
    }
    ?>
```

[image: this is what it says to do, delete the contact.html??]

Comment: do i need to put the email in at the bottom, where it reads "if there is no error send the email" put her email in the "$youremail;" ??

Comment: so now the screen after the email has been sent is just blank

Comment: you haven't gave any header location to redirect to contact.html page. Thats why @SaciBasaran

Comment: Now use. I Edited my answer. At the end of the page, i added header location. Use. You downvoted my answer?

Comment: i haven't down voted anything, dont even know how to do that? i will try what you have said thanks

Comment: Yeah. copy and paste. check and let me know @SaciBasaran

Comment: it goes back to the contact page which is better, not sure if the email has gone through I have emailed my client to see if it has worked

Comment: Ok. Don't Worry  @SaciBasaran. Everyone faces problem. Let's see what your client reply.

Comment: Yeah @SaciBasaran. Wait for 15-20 min. Busy in one work. I'll just come to your question. Sorry.